# GCP error reporting stacktrace sample is not detected

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently trying to implement the GCP error reporting for a Symfony project (PHP) in order to report any errors especially the stack trace of the application. The implementation is done by using the **Google Cloud Client Library**. However it appear that GCP is not detecting the stacktrace that I'm sending. Below is a screenshot of how it look like on the interface:

[image]

As documented in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.events/report#ReportedErrorEvent). I have to precise the type of message that I'm sending to the ReportedEventError (If i'm not mistaken the message should be prefix by the **'PHP Fatal Error'**) string in order for the message to be recognized as a stacktrace. But that didn't worked.

In order for you to help me solve my issues below is the JSON paylaod of what is send by the Google Cloud Client Library.

```js
  {
    "insertId": "INSERT ID ",
    "jsonPayload": {
      "context": {
        "httpRequest": {
          "responseStatusCode": 500,
          "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36",
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "/ping/edit",
          "remoteIp": "172.18.0.1"
        },
        "reportLocation": {
          "functionName": "editAction",
          "filePath": "/app/src/NS/PingBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php",
          "lineNumber": 24
        }
      },
      "message": "PHP Fatal error: #0 [internal function]: NS\\CommonBundle\\EventListener\\ExceptionListener->onKernelException(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\GetResponseForExceptionEvent), 'kernel.exceptio...', Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher))\n#1 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php(104): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\GetResponseForExceptionEvent), 'kernel.exceptio...', Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher))\n#2 [internal function]: Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener->__invoke(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\GetResponseForExceptionEvent), 'kernel.exceptio...', Object(Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))\n#3 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(212): call_user_func(Object(Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener), Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\GetResponseForExceptionEvent), 'kernel.exceptio...', Object(Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))\n#4 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(44): Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Array, 'kernel.exceptio...', Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\GetResponseForExceptionEvent))\n#5 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php(146): Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exceptio...', Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\GetResponseForExceptionEvent))\n#6 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php(230): Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exceptio...', Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\GetResponseForExceptionEvent))\n#7 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php(79): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handleException(Object(Exception), Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1)\n#8 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(171): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1, true)\n#9 /app/web/app_dev.php(28): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request))\n#10 {main}",
      "serviceContext": {
        "service": "hummingbird-sf"
      },
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.clouderrorreporting.v1beta1.ReportedErrorEvent"
    },
    "httpRequest": {
      "requestMethod": "GET",
      "requestUrl": "/ping/edit",
      "status": 500,
      "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36",
      "remoteIp": "172.18.0.1"
    },
    "resource": {
      "type": "reported_errors",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "<project_id>"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2019-12-09T14:33:51.792619820Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "logName": "projects/<project_id>/logs/clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com%2Freported_errors",
    "sourceLocation": {
      "file": "/app/src/NS/PingBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php",
      "line": "24",
      "function": "editAction"
    },
    "receiveTimestamp": "2019-12-09T14:33:51.792619820Z"
  }
```

*Note*: I also try to remove the location which didn't work either. As for the Symfony framework integration this solution didn't work too for others reasons...

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I had was that I used the Symfony default's method to print the error. In order to resolve this issue I replace this piece of code

```php
$this->stacktrace->getTraceAsString()
```

by

```php
(string) $this->stacktrace
```

and the stacktrace appear.

Comment: What was the actual output difference?